# Problema con '',"" al implementar código JavaScript en HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

Estoy generando un botón para eliminar registros de una tabla, concretamente quiero colocar una alerta de confirmación a mi botón

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código, como se puede observar estoy usando también PHP, el problema es que cuando coloco la instrucción JavaScript me da un error de sintaxis

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$html .= '<td>
<a href="delete_contratos.php?CveContrato=' . $CveContrato . ' " onclick="return confirm('Estás seguro que deseas eliminar el registro? ');"><img src="img/expedientes/eliminar.png" height="40" width="40" /></a>
</td>';
```

Como puedo usar las comillas para que interprete correctamente la instruccion JavaScript, muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: quedate siempre con comillas dobles ;)

Comment: Si pongo las comillas dobles en el mensaje, ignora el código JS y no solicita la confirmación

Comment: cambia `confirm('...')` por `confirm(\'...\')`

Comment: @gbianchi En mi caso siempre uso comillas simples por dos motivos: 1) Mi editor me pinta mejor las variables y código PHP concatenado, y 2) Evito problemas con javascript (al generarlo desde PHP) sin tener que escaparlo siempre cuando son líneas demasiado largas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tenes que escapar la comilla simple utilizando la barra invertida `\`.

#### Ejemplo:

```php
$html .= '<td>
<a href="delete_contratos.php?CveContrato=' . $CveContrato . ' " onclick="return confirm(\'Estás seguro que deseas eliminar el registro?\');"><img src="img/expedientes/eliminar.png" height="40" width="40" /></a>
</td>';
```

#### Más info:

- [Manual de PHP > Cadenas de caracteres > Entrecomillado simple](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)

Comment: Me funciono perfecto, esa era la solución, no sabía que se podía concatenar de esa manera, un saludo